# Are there any tools that can optimize a LaTeX formula?

Tags: math-mode

I am using mathtype to typeset equations and those equations can be copied as LaTeX.

For example,

[image]

is copied as

```
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{e^{ - i\phi /2}}}\\
{{e^{i\phi /2}}}
\end{array}} \right)
```

But there is obviously some redundant { and } symbol

more succinctly, it can be written as

```
\left(\begin{array}{c}
e^{-i\phi/2}\\
e^{i\phi/2}
\end{array}\right)
```

I am wondering, are there tools or program that can optimize or simplify LaTeX code like the above while maintain the same equation content? The main purpose is to remove redundant { and }

Comment: Just type in the code as `\begin{pmatrix} e^{-i\phi/2} \\ e^{i\phi/2} \end{pmatrix}` that's easier than going back and forth from an external program.

Comment: even better would be `\begin{pmatrix}` instead of `\left(\begin{array}{c}` (shorter and better output. In the end it is quicker and easier to learn to type the expressions directly rather than clean up automatically generated code.

Comment: oh @egreg was saying the same:-)

Comment: And the environment is available from within a shortcut with a modern editor.

Comment: Also, isn't better to use `\sfrac{\phi}{2}` instead of `\phi/2`?

Comment: @gvgramazio No.

Comment: @egreg Why not? (a serious question even if maybe stupid)

Comment: @gvgramazio `\sfrac` is at most good for recipe books.

Comment: Hi, @egreg thank you for comment. Sorry, maybe I didn't say clearly. But what I want is a tool or a program to simplify latex formula, not rewrite a particular formula by hand

Comment: "simplified" front ends invariably produce code that is more complicated than necessary, because they try to take into account possible situations that are usually quite rare.  while handling exceptions can be complicated when entering code directly, the need to do so is usually so rare that it is quicker to learn the basic code.  untangling the output of gui and other simplified front ends can be a nightmare, and it is often not easily predicted *which* "extra" braces to eliminate.

Comment: The Lyx math front end produce just the clean and better code of the first comment. If  the dirty code of the question is pasted in a math  environment of LyX, the source code is maintained, and the editor window will show almost the final output, but without hiding the 3 redundant  groups, so it is easy clean those manually (although this way you will end with `array` instead of `pmatrix`).

Comment: Hi, @Fran. You know what. I ask this question exactly because I encountered redundant { } when paste mathtype latex into lyx, and found manually remove { } annoying...

Comment: Ooops, maybe you can take some comfort in the fact that is  more annoying clean it in a plain text editor that show also the non redundant curly braces  `:)` ... and in the fact that LyX is not so bad front-end for maths, so paste math code from another front end should not be a frequent task for a LyX user.